# Regarding the Single and the Double Dot within Directories

Tags: windows, linux, unix

Whenever we use the command:

```
dir --> in Windows
```

and

```
dir -a --> in Unix
```

We see 2 kinds of dots:

```
.
..
```

Appear in the directories.
Now in APUE by Stephens Rago, it says these are filenames and some books say these are directories.

What are these Dots about anyway?
Please provide an answer w.r.t. Windows as well as Unix if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the same for both platforms (and web based programming)

`.` represents the directory you are in and `..` represents the parent directory.

In HTML if you have a file e.g.: http://example.com/blog/index.html and you want to link to the image http://example.com/images/image.jpg you would put it in as such:

```
<img src="../images/image.jpg" />
```

As that tells the script to look in the PARENT directory and then `images/image.jpg`.

Comment: additon: just to let you know they aren't physical directories (rather references to those folders) - but i believe unix and windows (etc) substantiate them as such.

Comment: I changed the url's to example.com since mysite.com is an existing site and selling webhosting. I got a red popup alert stating that `mysite.com` is not permitted as an example url. I guess I'll probably find something about this on meta; *hm...*, interesting.