# PHP path issues (localhost and server)

Tags: php

How do you guys handle the path of files to work either localhost and server without changing the variables?

For example, I have this:

```
$path = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
returns C:\xampp\htdocs
```

This would probably work on a online server, but doesn't work on a localhost, because I need to set the folder name of my project.
So, in my 100 files (for example) I would have to change to whenever I want to work in localhost:

```
$path = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . "/myproject/";
```

So I thought about a variable with a certain condition which would understand if it's localhost or server.

```
$path = (strpos(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]), "xampp") == false ? realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) : realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . '/myproject');
```

And all I had to do:

```
<link href="<?php echo $path . '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css';?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

The above code does not work (at least in localhost, I haven't tried in a real server), because I get the following errors on console:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css

Which I understand, so I have tried to change my `$path` variable to:

```
$path = (strpos(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]), "xampp") == false ? realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) : 'http://localhost/myproject');
```

And I get in the console:

```
Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\backend\orders.php on line 6
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: How about `__DIR__` constant?

Comment: Do you really know what `realpath()` actually does?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk `__DIR__` returns "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\backend" and I need to get "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\". So, if I use something like: `$path = __DIR__ . "../"`, does not work.
`require_once($path . 'libs/products.php');`
`Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\backend../libs/products.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please learn how filesystem paths work. If you'd like to target one directory up, then use `dirname(__DIR__)` or just add another slash in `myproject\backend HERE -> \ <- HERE ../libs` as you need to separate `..` entry from others.

Comment: Nop, that still does not work. By using: `$path = __DIR__ . "\..";` or `dirname(__DIR__)` I still get the same error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css`
If I go to the ChromeConsole and check the `<head>`, this is my final url: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css'/>`
Which, btw, I output it this way:
`<link href="<?php echo $path . '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css';?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is to just create a local site with the same folder structure than your live site. I suspect you're doing it that way only because you aren't aware of [Apache virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).

In any case, it's always practical to abstract paths as much as possible and constants are always a good choice. I typically define two:

- `WEB_ROOT` to be used in URLs (in my case it's often just `/`)
- `FS_ROOT` to be used in file system paths

You can feed them with hard-coded values in a settings file or dynamically calculating them. `FS_ROOT` is trivial to populate: you can use `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` for very old PHP versions.

*Surprisingly, `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` does not provide accurate info in all hosting services.*

---

**Edit #1:** I've appreciated a little base misconception in some of your comments so I'll try to shed some light on it.

Finding stuff on the Internet is not the same as finding stuff in your hard disc. The former makes use of URLs:

- `http://example.com/blog/latest-news?page=3`

The latter makes use of file system paths:

- `/home/alice/pictures/kitten.jpg`
- `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Shopping list.txt`

In a web based PHP application you normally need to use **both** and you need to know the difference. You cannot use a URL to grab random files from a computer (not even yours) and you cannot use a file system path to grab anything from someone else's computer. This:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css'/>
```

... is plain wrong because your linking a public resource with a file system path that will only work in your PC.

And one more thing... Most operating systems have adopted the convention to consider `.` and `..` [special directory names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479744/regarding-the-single-and-the-double-dot-within-directories). That convention has been extended to URLs. But you must handle them as any other path component: it's `backend/..` and not `backend..` for the same reason that `foo/bar` is not the same as `foobar`.

**Edit #2:** Even if you don't use class auto-loading or the include_path directive, it's trivial to load your application wide settings file, either with absolute paths:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../conf/configuration.php');
```

... or relative paths:

```
require_once('../conf/configuration.php');
```

IHMO, doing this once per script, in the top level PHP file, is a huge benefit over calculating all application paths every single time you use them.

Comment: How do you use only "/"? 
And one of the things that makes me wonder why use constants in this problems is that, for using a constant, you need to include a file, and to include a file we go back to the same problem with paths.