# VISUAL STUDIO, MFC PROJECT

Tags: visual-studio-2010, path, mfc, visual-studio-2013

I am running a third party sample MFC project:
In the "Output" tab of a successful build, this is shown:
1>  MDIBars.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\Samples\MDIBars - Copy'\'.'\'..\Bin\MDIBarsD.exe

(I had to add two pairs of ' to get it to post correctly)

What does this mean?  Specifically, the ".\" & "..\"

I know that .\ is the directory the .sln is in...
I know that ..\ means one up from where the directory the .sln is in...

The directory just before the .\ is the location of the .sln.  So it appears there are identical consecutive directories in the file path?  It looks recursive.

What am I missing?

The MDIBars Property Pages/Config Properties/Debugging/working directory is C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\Bin <\n new line>
The MSVS2013 solution file is here: C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\Samples\MDIBars - Copy<\n to make this post clear>

The solution file is called MDIBars.sln

ProjectDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\Samples\MDIBars - Copy

Notice they do not have the MDIBars Property Pages/Config Properties/Debugging/working directory where the project .sln file is located.

Any help is appreciated...Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding the Single and the Double Dot within Directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479744/regarding-the-single-and-the-double-dot-within-directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is just an artefact of concatenating paths automatically.

`.` means "current directory", `..`, as you noted, means "one level up".
 `c:\xyz\.\abc` is the same as `c:\xyz\abc` and `c:\xyz\..\abc` reduces to `c:\abc` (think of it as going to xyz, then one level up and to abc)

Comment: Thanks - So, MDIBars.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\Samples\MDIBars - Copy\.\..\Bin\MDIBarsD.exe translates to MDIBars.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBarPro\Samples\MDIBars - Copy\<go one up>\Bin\MDIBarsD.exe

Comment: your exe should have ended up in samples\bin.