# Count total number of rows from all the files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have a folder `/data` and this folder has around 50,000 r datasets. Each dataset starting with `File_`. It goes like this.

```
   File_1323.rds
   File_3223.rds
   File_5122.rds
   File_8273.rds
   .
   .
   .
```

I need help counting the total number of rows in all these files. Not one file at a time. Total number of rows from all these files combined. Any suggestions much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cat File_*.rds | wc -l` should work, assuming each line of a file is one "row". Edit: Scratch that. I'm pretty sure 50,000 files would exceed the maximum number of args. So you may need to use `find -name "File_*.rds" -exec cat {} \;` instead of `cat File_*`. And if you don't want to recurse into subdirs, then add `-maxdepth 1` after `find`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total number of lines in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026533/total-number-of-lines-in-a-directory), [How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358540/how-to-count-all-the-lines-of-code-in-a-directory-recursively)

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

Use `wc(1)`:

```
wc -l File_*.rds
```

Or, to get just the number (for usage in scripts):

```
wc -l File_*.rds | awk '/ total/{ print $1 }'
```

However 50'000 might exceed the "maximum number of arguments" limit, so use `find ... -exec...`:

```
find . -name 'File_*.rds' -exec cat "{}" + | wc -l
```

Comment: You can minimize the number of times `cat` is called by using `-exec cat {} +`

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. ! Just learned about `+` :)