# System.IO.Directory.Exists does not work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.directory

When string "D:\test\..." is passed to `System.IO.Directory.Exists` method, it returns `True` on my machine. I have checked the following code;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Directory.Exists("D:\\test\\..."))
        Console.WriteLine("Directory exist.");  //Control gets here
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Does not exist.");
}
```

This happens even when a directory with name "..." (triple dots) does not exist at the specified location.

Further investigation on this shows that somehow internally it's only checking for "D:" by completely ignoring last part of the string. Since the parent directory exists, it's returning true.

**I want to know if there is any way to check without cutting off the trailing dots?**

Are there any such scenarios where the result from the `Directory.Exists` method could be different from expected?

**Update:**
If I enter the same string "D:\test\..." in the address bar of windows explorer and hit enter, there it is able to identify that it can't find such directory. Is there any way to get similar behavior?

Note: I know that directory with such name cannot exist, but I am getting input string from the user, so input to this method could be anything.

Comment: Feed the text through IO.Path.GetFullPath() first, it'll process those dots and let you know where the filesystem is really thinkin about. Three dots will be interpreted as dot-dot=up then dot=here. Another fictional file is NUL, and I think the old COM1, COM2 etc still exist

Comment: Never call this function. It's bugged in the spec.

Comment: `...` would be an invalid directory anyway, you can't create such a directory.

Comment: `input string from user, so input to this method could be anything` ... okay, but sometimes even users need to use their brain ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding the Single and the Double Dot within Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3479744/1260204)

Comment: `Note: I know that directory with such name can not exist but I am getting input string from user, so input to this method could be anything.` <= **Don't trust user input! Ever!** Always validate and sanitize it before you do anything with it.

Comment: @Igor, How can I validate user input in this case? If path "C:\test\..." means "C:" for system, is there any way to consider it as it is and tell if directory with name "..." does not (or can not) exist.

Comment: 2 options that come to mind right away are: 1. Regular expression on input with allowed characters. 2. Get the Absolute path (combine input with whatever directory you are applying it to) and see if it is based in whatever directory it should be confined to.

Comment: @Igor, I just checked the same string in address bar of windows explorer. There its able to identify properly. Its showing that it cant find such directory. I want similar behavior.

Comment: `I want similar behavior.` <= This is the way the API works. If you want something else then you have to write it yourself, find another library, or put a ticket request in with Microsoft to change the behavior (don't hold your breath on that one though). Or you can do what I suggested above and pick one of those 2 fairly easy to implement items.

Comment: Also if you use a DOS command there is no error: `CD Test\...` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a behavior of Win32.

In fact, If I create a folder named `...` by the command below (a creation of the folder in a normal way doesn't allow):

```
mkdir \\?\c:\...
```

The folder `...` redirects to C:\ itself. So I think the folder `...` represents the current folder (C:\ in this case) and it exists always.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are going "D:\" disk again.

The escape character expression "D:\test\..." means Disk named "D" and it is there.

If you change the disk letter. You will get "Does not exist.". Here is your answer.

D:\ --> D:\test --> .. comand and going D:\ again.

and you can't create folder named "...". you will get "The parameter is incorrect" error.